# Javascript - How do I make a small function that checks if A = 1 and B = 3 / 4 / 5 and do that for 8 values of A?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, math

I made a site for a school project and I figured I needed a function to check wind direction stuff, this is what I came to:
This is definitely not the best way to do it so I was wondering if anyone could compact it down to something shorter.
Thanks in advance!

```
            if (
            (A == 1 & B == 8) ||
            (A == 1 & B == 1) ||
            (A == 1 & B == 2) ||
            (A == 2 & B == 1) ||
            (A == 2 & B == 2) ||
            (A == 2 & B == 3) ||
            (A == 3 & B == 2) ||
            (A == 3 & B == 3) ||
            (A == 3 & B == 4) ||
            (A == 4 & B == 3) ||
            (A == 4 & B == 4) ||
            (A == 4 & B == 5) ||
            (A == 5 & B == 4) ||
            (A == 5 & B == 5) ||
            (A == 5 & B == 6) ||
            (A == 6 & B == 5) ||
            (A == 6 & B == 6) ||
            (A == 6 & B == 7) ||
            (A == 7 & B == 6) ||
            (A == 7 & B == 7) ||
            (A == 7 & B == 8) ||
            (A == 8 & B == 7) ||
            (A == 8 & B == 8) ||
            (A == 8 & B == 1)
            ){action} 
        else if (
            (A == 1 & B == 4) ||
            (A == 1 & B == 5) ||
            (A == 1 & B == 6) ||
            (A == 2 & B == 5) ||
            (A == 2 & B == 6) ||
            (A == 2 & B == 7) ||
            (A == 3 & B == 6) ||
            (A == 3 & B == 7) ||
            (A == 3 & B == 8) ||
            (A == 4 & B == 7) ||
            (A == 4 & B == 8) ||
            (A == 4 & B == 1) ||
            (A == 5 & B == 8) ||
            (A == 5 & B == 1) ||
            (A == 5 & B == 2) ||
            (A == 6 & B == 1) ||
            (A == 6 & B == 2) ||
            (A == 6 & B == 3) ||
            (A == 7 & B == 2) ||
            (A == 7 & B == 3) ||
            (A == 7 & B == 4) ||
            (A == 8 & B == 3) ||
            (A == 8 & B == 4) ||
            (A == 8 & B == 5)
            ) {action}
        else {action}
```

Comment: `B` is either `A - 1`, `A` or `A + 1` in the `if` case and `A + 4 - 1`, `A + 4` or `A + 4 + 1` in the `else if` case (+ some overflow)

Comment: "_wind direction stuff_" What are the raw values? Or if these numbers are the raw values (assuming wind directions), what is the actual goal of the entire operation?

Comment: can you clarify it lit bit?

Comment: what are the ranges of the variables? do you have only integer values between one and eight?

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce this cascade with

```
if (B == A || B == (A % 8) + 1 || B == ((A + 6) % 8) + 1) {

} else if (B == ((A + 2) % 8) + 1 || B == ((A + 3) % 8) + 1 || B == ((A + 4) % 8) + 1) {

} else {

}
```

It's even less complex with a helper function:

```
// map input from range [0, 13] into range [1, 8]
const m = v => ((v + 7) % 8) + 1;

if (B == A || B == m(A + 1) || B == m(A - 1)) {

} else if (B == m(A + 3) || B == m(A + 4) || B == m(A + 5)) {

} else {

}
```

You can test it with:

```
// map input from range [0, 13] into range [1, 8]
const m = v => ((v + 7) % 8) + 1;

for (let A = 1; A <= 8; ++A) {
    for (let B = 1; B <= 8; ++B) {
        if (B == A || B == m(A + 1) || B == m(A - 1)) {
            console.log("A = " + A + ", B = " + B + ": Action 1");
        } else if (B == m(A + 3) || B == m(A + 4) || B == m(A + 5)) {
            console.log("A = " + A + ", B = " + B + ": Action 2");
        } else {
            console.log("A = " + A + ", B = " + B + ": Action 3");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably similar in principle to @Thomas Sablik's answer, but a bit easier for my brain to understand.

```js
const circle_number_numbers = 8;

function circle_number(n) {
  const modded = n % circle_number_numbers;
  return modded < 1 ? modded + circle_number_numbers : modded;
}

function sameish(a, b) {
  return a === circle_number(b) || a === circle_number(b + 1) || a === circle_number(b - 1);
}

function oppositeish(a, b) {
  return sameish(a, b + (circle_number_numbers / 2));
}

function test(a, b) {
  if(sameish(a, b)) {
    console.log(a, b, 'sameish');
  } else if(oppositeish(a, b)) {
    console.log(a, b, 'oppositeish');
  } else {
    console.log(a, b, 'other');
  }
}

test(2, 5);
test(2, 3);
test(2, 2);
test(2, 1);
test(2, 8);
test(1, 8);
test(2, 8);
test(1, 5);
test(1, 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could caluculate the distance between `A` and `B`. In the calculation, you've to keep in mind, that the maximum distance between the points is `6`. If the distance gets bigger, then `B` is next to `A` on the left. Also, when checking complement sector, `A` must not grow above `8`, it must take the direction from the next round instead. Here's more or less straightforward code:

```js
const A = 1, B = 3; // This is the data

function distance (a, b, R) {
  a = (a + R > 8) ? a - R : a + R; // Put a to the next round if needed
  const d = Math.abs(b - a);       // True distance
  return (d > 6) ? -1 : d;         // Return the modified distance
};

if (distance(A, B, 0) < 2) {
  console.log('Same sector');
} else if (distance(A, B, 4) < 2) {
  console.log('Complement sector');
} else {
  console.log('Supplement sector');
}
```

The code can be used with zero-based direction indices too, only `a` needs to be limited to `7` in `distance` function.

Here's [a fiddle to play with](https://jsfiddle.net/yspdnakm/).